# Repeat table title along with thead in flyingsaucer pdf

Tags: java, css, scala, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

If we set -fs-table-paginate to paginate, the `<thead />` element of the table will repeat in every page if the table spans over multiple pages in a pdf.

Is there a way to repeat other content along with `<thead />` in subsequent pages?

for eg: How do we repeat the **title** of the table(which sits outside `<thead />`) in each page in the rendered pdf?

Comment: This would be an iText question if you used [iText 7: converting HTML to PDF](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) to convert HTML to PDF, but you don't. You use an old third party tool that isn't endorsed by iText Group. Please try `<thead>` with iText 7 and pdfHTML, and update your question if it doesn't work.

Comment: We use below version of flying saucer in our scala project.                                  lazy val flyingSaucer = "9.0.9"
  val flyingSaucerCore =  "org.xhtmlrenderer" % "flying-saucer-core" % Version.flyingSaucer
  val flyingSaucerPdf  =  "org.xhtmlrenderer" % "flying-saucer-pdf" % Version.flyingSaucer excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "bouncycastle")

Comment: You have just confirmed that you're using Flying Saucer, so why is this question still tagged as an iText question? If you want support, use iText. Very few Flying Saucer questions get answered here.

Comment: This is top google result for flying saucer thead. It's super helpful that I found `-fs-table-paginate` option from your question text! 